# Adding columns to list in python

Tags: python

I have a list `arr1` in python -

```
for row in arr1:
    print(row)
```

This gives the contents as follows-

```
['1', '0', '86.0', '49.0', '70.0', 'NA', '87.0', 'NA', '0']
['1', '4320', 'NA', 'NA', '70.0', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', '0']
['1', '5646', '91.0', '58.0', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', '96.6', '1']
['1', '5703', '140.0', '73.0', '91.0', '32.0', 'NA', 'NA', '1']
['1', '6342', '139.0', '90.0', '107.0', '29.0', '101.0', 'NA', '1']
['1', '6609', '152.0', '75.0', '109.0', '30.0', '101.0', 'NA', '1']
['1', '6894', '140.0', '79.0', '84.0', 'NA', '98.0', 'NA', '1']
['1', '6957', '140.0', '72.0', '108.0', '31.0', '101.0', 'NA', '1']
```

Now, I want to add some columns to this based upon the values in first two columns. For example if first column is `1` and second column is `4320` add a new column with value `1` otherwise add `0`. I am new to python and not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for i,row in enumerate(arr1):
    if row[0]=='1' and row[1]=='4320':
        val = '1'
    else:
        val = '0'
    arr1[i].append(val)
```